# Enquiry on Query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as below:

```
Category | Type | Rank 
Milk        1      1 
Milk        2      2
Milk        3      3
Chocolate   1      2
Candy       1      1
```

Any idea to achieve the output of below with a flat SQL query:

```
Category 
Milk         

Query must satisfy the below conditions:
 1. Only Type 1 and Rank 1 will be selected. 
 2. Only Category that has Type 1 and Type 2 will be selected.
```

In the sample data above, only Milk that satisfy the conditions mentioned above.

My query is below. But it's incorrect, because it will return Candy as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category 
FROM table 
WHERE Type = 1 AND rank = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select category
from t
group by category
having sum(case when type = 1 and rank = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Assuming no duplicates, this can be simplified to:

```
select category
from t
where (type = 1 and rank = 1) or type = 2
group by category
having count(distinct type) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a5d5cc79dda498d3aa52bbe5dc9860c)**

```
select distinct category 
from table a
WHERE Type = 1 AND rank = 1 
and exists 
 (select 1 from table b where a.category=b.category and type in (1,2) 
     group by category having count(distinct type)=2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
category
Milk
```

Comment: Looks like this will work, but the subquery is more complex than it needs to be.  Since you are already only selecting types where rank 1 exists, the subquery should only need to check whether rank 2 also exists for each category.  (Also, you have `where` twice in the subquery -- second one should be `and`.)